# Postgresql, how to call a specific value in CASE WHEN query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, case, aggregate-functions

I have a query, where I need to use two numeric parameters (27133 for 2012 and 32890 for 2013) in CASE WHEN structure, but these parameters are values from another table, which is `insert into total_srti_by_year`.

How can I avoid hard coding?
Below what I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE total_srti_by_year (
maxsrti numeric NOT NULL,
year int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (year)
);

insert into total_srti_by_year 
select max(company_abc.srti), company_abc.year
from company_abc 
group by year

UPDATE company_abc as cm
SET cls = case 
            WHEN  cm.year = 2012 and cm.srti <= 27133*0.8 THEN 'A'
            WHEN  cm.year = 2012 and cm.srti <= 27133*0.95 THEN 'B'
            WHEN  cm.year = 2013 and cm.srti <= 32890*0.8 THEN 'A'
            WHEN  cm.year = 2013 and cm.srti <= 32890*0.95 THEN 'B'
END
FROM company_abc;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the intermediate table. You can self-join the table and update it at the same time, like so:

```
update company_abc as c
set cls = case 
    when c.srti <= t.maxsrti * 0.8  then 'a'
    when c.srti <= t.maxsrti * 0.95 then 'b'        
end
from (
    select year, max(srti) as maxsrti
    from company_abc
    group by year
) t 
where c.year = t.year;
```

If might also be a good idea to filter out rows that you don't want to update. For this, you can adapt the `where` clause:

```
where c.year = t.year and c.srti <= t.maxsrti * 0.95
```

If you have a primary key, say `id`, you can also use window functions rather than aggregation:

```
update company_abc as c
set cls = case 
    when t.ratio <= 0.8  then 'a'
    when t.ratio <= 0.95 then 'b'        
end
from (
    select t.*, 
        1.0 * srti / max(srti) over(partition by year) as ratio
    from company_abc
) t 
where c.id = t.id and t.ratio <= 0.95
```